# Service's attributes and methods in angular libraries

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing an Angular (6) library for internal use for my company. The lib basically has components and some basic services; the components are working as intended but the services not, when I import them and inject in a component for use, I do not have access to their attributes and methods and keep getting this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'exampleServiceMethod' does not exist on type 'SampleService'
```

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable( {
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleService {
  exampleServiceMethod() {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
 }
```

The component in the consumer app using the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SampleService} from 'testlib';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Consumer App';
  comment: string;

  constructor (private _service: SampleService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this._service.exampleServiceMethod());
  }
}
```

EDIT: Consumer App's `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SampleModule, SampleService } from 'testlib';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SampleModule // testlib main module
  ],
  providers: [SampleService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

PS: I've registered the service in both providers array in the lib itself and in the consuming app.

Comment: Did you try adding `public` for service method?

Comment: @AliShahbaz with the `private` object you can access all service method in this component.ts.

Comment: @AliShahbaz Yes, I've tried adding public for the method, but I get the same error.

Comment: Don't use `providedIn: 'root'` in your service, Just `provide` it in your module.ts under `providers: [SampleService]`.

Comment: I am not sure if you have imported the correct service. Can you make sure you don't have a duplicate service which you have imported and provided which does not have that method?

Comment: @ShashikantDevani I've tested that also, same result :(

Comment: @VinodBhavnani The consumer app does not have any services, nor the library (except `SampleService` of course)

Comment: Your import path says 'testlib'. Not sure what that is.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly imported service? It should have like this `./testlib/sample.service` instead of `import {SampleService} from 'testlib';`. If you not rename anything.

Comment: Check @ShashikantDevani s comment. Exactly what I wanted to specify.

Comment: they are two distinct projects living in different directories, `testlib` is generated via `npm pack` command and installed via `npm install ..\ng-lib\dist\testlib-0.1.0.tgz --production`

Comment: Can you post your app module code here?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani Done, post updated

Comment: Can you try to put a constructor in the service with a console log and see if that is getting called when app-root is instantiated?

Comment: It shows nothing :(

Comment: What is `SampleModule`? In this module have you provide `SampleService` in `providedIn`?

Comment: @ShashikantDevani `SampleModule` is `testlib`'s main module, and yes, `SampleService` is provided there.

Comment: Don't include `SampleService` in both `modules`. Just provide in `app.module.ts`. Or Just Provide inside `testlib module` don't provide in `app.module`

Comment: @ShashikantDevani I have tested it in both modules, same results unfortunately.